# Colour specific regression line - extraction of aov, shapiro and fligner on text file

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

Here is my current code:

```
dat = data.frame(matrix(c(rnorm(20), rep(c(1:5),10), rep(seq(1,4),5)), ncol=3))
colnames(dat)<- c('var1','var2','var3')
ggplot(dat, aes(y=var1,x=var2,colour=var3)) + 
    geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='aov',se=F)
```

I'd like to display aov lines for each colour. How can I do that ?

Moreover I'd like to extract the `summary(aov())` of the displayed lines on a text file.
And also extract the tests for the assumptions of these `aov()`... In other words I'd like to extract the `fligner.test(dat$var1~var2)` and `fligner.test(dat$var1~var3)` and the `shapiro.test(residuals(aov(var1~var2*var3)))`.

Is there a way of doing all that by taking advantage of ggplot package or do I have to manipulate all the data through for loops ?

Comment: I think you should divide your question in two parts - one relating the problem with plotting of data and other relating other tests and writing text files. ggplot package won't be the way to get test results of shapiro and fliger and export them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have separate line for each `var3`, it should be set as factor inside `ggplot()` function.

```
ggplot(dat,aes(y=var1,x=var2,colour=as.factor(var3))) + 
   geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='aov',se=F)
```

Comment: Thank you Didzis Elferts ! That is already one thing done. Now does anybody have an idea about how to extract results of stats test on these regressions ?